# How to specify default __import__?

Tags: python, import, sandbox

I am trying to learn how to create a simple sandbox environment in Python. To do so I want to disable some `__import__` modules and make it default. That way anything someone runs a program, `__import__` will already be specified.

What is the way to do this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve. Are you looking to disable the import of certain modules while also automatically importing others? Is this for running untrusted code? You should read through some other questions on Python sandboxing before attempting this - essentially, CPython sandboxes not backed by OS level sandboxing technicques are demonstrably weak. I believe PyPy has a secure sandboxing system but you should verify this yourself. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sandbox+python

Comment: Also, what have you tried already?

Comment: This is for running untrusted code. Pypy is great, but for learning purposes is too complex. I am looking to disable imports by the method of del modules from the dictionary. However I don't know how to default the process.

Comment: I think the appropriate action would be to have a wrapper script which establishes/secures the environment and then loads/executes the untrusted code. Just be aware that compromising the environment would probably not be difficult for a skilled user/Googler.